# Create single value from Latitude and Longitude pair in PHP

Tags: php, latitude-longitude

I'm working on a Google Maps project within a PHP application. I need to find a way to store a latitude and longitude pair as a singular value. I'm using this to help store markers with identical coordinates.

Is there way I can encode the latitude/longitude pair into a single string? I would like something like:

```
$lat = 45.18392;
$long = 62.18293;

// Would return a single string like 893jfd8sj39k
$single_string = make_single_string($lat, $long);

function make_single_string($lat, $long)
{
    // Do something here with $lat and $long
    return $single_string;
}
```

The most important part of the function is that it must return the same string EVERY time.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
function make_single_string($lat, $long)
{
    $single_string = md5( $lat.'-'.$long );
    return $single_string;
}
```

result will be something like this:

```
04f59f6c007149079d0b5cc81ee0d25f
```

Comment: Wouldn't exactly be reversible though... OP didn't mention it had to be, but one can assume it should be.

Comment: Well from OP's "The most important part of the function is that it must return the same string EVERY time." remark I got that not being reversible is not an issue. I'm not sure though.

Comment: +1 Thanks...gave the accept to @powtac because he was 1 minute faster.

Comment: @Sardine Actually I was 1 minute faster, 11 mins **ago** vs 10 mins **ago**, but no problem I'm glad you got your answer :)

Comment: @Sardine why would you want to hash the string? this is a lot slower than simple concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a hash of both numbers:

```
function make_single_string($lat, $long)
{
    return md5($lat.'-'.$long);
}
```

Comment: Thanks...cannot believe I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 1):

Cant you concatenate the string on the return? with .'s...

return $lat . "," . $long;

Comment: That's a very good point. I'm using the value as an array key, so I really only want to use alphanumeric values.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you're not using an object for this?

```
$lat = 45.18392;
$long = 62.18293;

$pos = array(
    'lat'=>$lat,
    'long'=>$long
);
```

It's much more readable and as a bonus you don't have to parse it later (can be easily serialized as well).

Comment: I was trying to keep this question as focused as possible, but yes, I'm storing all of the data for the marker in an array. I want to store all markers in the same location in the same value value. I need the single value to be utilized as the array key.

Answer (score 1):

If you want reversibility (and you probably do) then you need to come up with a standard input format. Assuming your latitude can go between +/-90, and your longitudes between +/-180, you could do something like:

1. Make sure the latitude and longitude have signs. If positive, prepend the `+` sign.
2. Zero-pad on the front to two digits (for latitude) and three digits (for longitude). 9.2 degrees of latitude would become `+09.2`.
3. Zero-pad on the end to however many significant digits you want (say, six). 9.2 degrees of latitude would then become `+09.200000`.
4. Convert `+`, `-`, and `.` to some kind of standard notation. Say, `P` for `+`, `M` for `-`, and `d` for `.`. For 9.2 degrees of latitude you'd get `P09d200000`.
5. Concatenate the latitude and longitude.

Then you get a string that's reversible and only has alphanumeric characters in it. You might not need something this fancy, though.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response! I don't need reversibility as I am storing the raw values in an array. I just need a way to store markers with the same lat/long pairs in the same array. I was trying to find a single value that I could generate and use as an array key.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for really exists, and is not as simple as `md5( $lat.'-'.$long );`, as to be effective must be done before a process of generalization.

It´s called [Geohash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash). In PHP there are different implementations. [This is good](http://www.elphin.com/downloads/geohash-php-class/), but Google offers several options.

Comment: I was looking for a way to encode lat/lng values which can be reversed, Geohash is perfect because you don't have to use an external service to do the encoding. I found this implementation ([skthon/geohash](https://github.com/skthon/geohash)) as the site you linked to no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just concat them?

```
$string = $lat . "-" . $long;
```

I mean if you really wanted to I supposed you could take the above and use `md5` on it:

```
$string = md5($lat . "-" . $long);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class or plain object.

**class**

```
class Coord {
   public $lat;
   public $long;

   __construct($lat, $long) {
      $this->lat = $lat;
      $this->long = $long;
   }
}

$coord = new Coord(45.18392, 62.18293);
echo $coord->lat;
echo $coord->long;
```

**plain object**

```
$coords = new stdClass();
$coords->lat = 45.18392;
$coords->long = 62.18293;
echo $coord->lat;
echo $coord->long;
```

If you needs to save these in a database, you could serialize the objects into a string, then unserialize as you pull them again from the database.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php